# Corona SDK ScrollView preventing the masked area from being touched?

Tags: coronasdk

I want to set my newscrollview to a specific height

there are two ways to do that

1 - either by setting the height property,
or
2 - by using masks

the problem is when you change the ScollView size it changes only the look of the scrollview and it will not prevent the hidden area from being touch enabled? is this a bug?

here is the code

```
 local widget = require "widget"

 local myscrollview = widget.newScrollView{
    height = 300,
    maskFile="mask.png"
 }

 local obj1 = display.newRect(0, 0, display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight)
 obj1:setReferencePoint( display.TopLeftReferencePoint ) 
 obj1:setFillColor(255,27,27)
 obj1.x = 0
 obj1.y = 0

 local obj2 = display.newRect(0, 0, display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight)
 obj2:setReferencePoint( display.TopLeftReferencePoint ) 
 obj2:setFillColor(0,27,27)
 obj2.x = 0
 obj2.y = 260


 myscrollview:insert(obj1)
 myscrollview:insert(obj2)
```

is there any way to prevent the masked area from being touched?

Thanks in Advance

**UPDATED here is the mask.png:**

[image: here is the mask.png]

Comment: What are the dimensions of your mask.png ??

Comment: @SatheeshJM I have updated the question with the required file,Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I have figured it out :)

you have to add this line of code

```
    myscrollview.isHitTestMasked = true
```

see if you want the Documentation of 
[isHitTestMasked](http://developer.anscamobile.com/node/10370)

Thanks to anyone tried to solve :)

Comment: I actually tried that before.  Seems I made a spelling mistake. Duh!
I tried with myscrollview.isHitTestedMasked = true

Comment: @SatheeshJM sooo close.., mistakes like this always happen, I really should thank you for trying to help Satheesh, best regards in your life :)